Android: Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-sessions:[15.0.0, 16.0.0)
I'm using Firebase and OneSignal in my Android project for notification today suddenly I get this error:
Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-sessions:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
Versions that do not match:
  - 1.2.4
  - 1.2.3
  - 1.2.2
  - 1.2.1
  - 1.2.0
  - + 4 more
Required by:
    project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.6.4

I tried many solutions but noting works. Please help me to resolve the issue.
Here is my build.gradle file content:
dependencies {

    constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.5.0"
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.4.0'

    // material
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    // location
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:3.1.0'
    /*circular imageView */
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
    /*country code lib*/
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.4.2'
    /*circular viewpager indicator*/
    implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    /*expandable recyclerview*/
    implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.3'
    /*permissions handling lib*/
    implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.2.0'
    /* image loading lib*/
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    /*for network call*/
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.Quendel:Multiutils:2.0'


    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.3.1'

    // Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0'

    //lifecycle
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.6.1"

    // Room Database
    def room_version = "2.5.1"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

    // OneSignal
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[5.0.0, 5.99.99]'

    // spin kit (dialog)
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'

    // crop picture
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6'

    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.1'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0"
}

I tried by changing firebase boom version to latest version but error still the same.

Try again after removing OneSignal Library.
